# QPushButton not respecting QIcon mode changes

Tags: c++, qt, qpushbutton, qicon

When applying a `QIcon` with `QPushButton::setIcon()`, it appears that mode changes don't respect the mode changes set for the `QIcon`

```
QIcon helpIcon;
helpIcon.addPixmap(QPixmap(":/icons/style/help.png"), QIcon::Normal);
helpIcon.addPixmap(QPixmap(":/icons/style/help_hover.png"), QIcon::Active); //ignored?

QPushButton *myButton = new QPushButton(this);
myButton->setIcon(helpIcon);
```

What I would expect to happen is the icon should change from one pixmap to the other when the button is hovered. Instead, the icon stays the same. It only changes when the button is pressed. I've tried every combination of `QIcon::State` and `QIcon::Mode` with no change.

Running Qt 5.12.1

Comment: Would a QSS solution be suitable in your case? `QPushButton:hover ` works better for sure.

Comment: Not really because I scale the pixmap depending on the users DPI (not shown here)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this by subclassing `QPushButton` and listening for the enter and leave events. This class switches between base and hover icons. This is more useful for me vs stylesheets because I resize the icons based on the user's DPI.

```
class CustomButton : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    CustomButton(QWidget *parent = nullptr);

    void setBaseIcon(QIcon icon){
        baseIcon = icon;
        setIcon(baseIcon);
    }

    void setHoverIcon(QIcon icon){hoverIcon = icon;}

private:
    QIcon baseIcon;
    QIcon hoverIcon;

protected:
    virtual void enterEvent(QEvent *){
        setIcon(hoverIcon);
        update();
    }

    virtual void leaveEvent(QEvent *){
        setIcon(baseIcon);
        update();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simply how `QPushButton` handles states (and hence icon mode/state), which is different from `QToolButton`.  More specifically it is how the current `QStyle` subclass uses the button state information to paint the icon. For example, here is the `QPushButton::paintEvent()` [code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qpushbutton.cpp.html#_ZN11QPushButton10paintEventEP11QPaintEvent) (follow that to see `initStyleOption()` call where state data is initialized), then the style options are handed off to the currently active `QStyle` (which could be eg. WindowsVista/Macintosh/Fusion/StyleSheets depending on OS or settings). Then if we look at, for example, the relevant `QFusionStyle` [code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/styles/qfusionstyle.cpp.html#1774) we can see that the **icon `Active` mode is only used when the button has focus**. Or [same](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/styles/qcommonstyle.cpp.html#1367) in `QCommonStyle` (which Windows/WindowsVista/Macintosh styles all fall back to).

To work around this you could use CSS and set an `image` property for the `QPushButton:hover` state, or implement your own `QProxyStyle::drawControl()` method for the `CE_PushButtonLabel` control element.

CSS: `QPushButton:hover { image: url(/path/to/icon.png); }`